spring-data-mongodb v3.2.12 repository.findAll(pageable) very slow on MongoDB server v5.0
In spring-data-mongdb v3.2.12, the repository.findAll(pageable) query took 1280ms to finish on a collection of 2M records. But with the legacy spring-data-mongdb v2.2.12.release version, it only took 127ms on the same collection. The "pageable" parameter is like PageRequest.of(0,100,Sort.by(Direction.ASC,"createTimestamp"))
After turning on driver debug log, it showed that spring-data-mongdb v3.2.12 triggers "aggregate" query first and took 1131ms. But spring-data-mongdb v2.2.12.release triggers "count" query first and only took 1.34ms.
Any idea why spring-data-mongdb v3.2.12 is using the very slow "aggregate" query in the pagination?

With the introduction of MongoDB multi document transactions it was no longer possible to operate upon collection statistics for count queries. In order to get an exact count one needs to use the aggregation as described in the reference documentation.
You still may opt into count estimation (where possible) by setting MongoTemplate#useEstimatedCount(boolean) to true in your configuration.
